# How to get contact fields in custom activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity, field-mapping

I am new to the salesforce and I have created a custom activity(REST). In my `config.json` file > arguments.execute.inArguments, I want to get my contact fields.

I have following code:

```json
{
  "arguments": {
    "execute": {
      "inArguments": [
        {
          "fName": "{{Contact.Attribute.YOPTO.First_Name__c}}"
        }
      ],
      "url": "https://backend-service"
    }
  }
}
```

When I get the call in my backend-service, the `fName` field is always empty. I got so far using this [documentation.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/how-data-binding-works.html#supported-methods-of-data-binding)

My data extension structure is following:
[image]

What should be the correct mustache template mapping in this case to get the `fName` field of the contact.

Comment: hows it connected in data designer?

Comment: You mean  how its connected in the journey, as data extension?

Comment: no how is it connected within data designer inside contact builder